# search by class in string javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

Let's suppose I have this string:

```js
var myhtml= "<html><body><div class='header'>Welcome</div><div class='news' id='new_1'>Lorem ipsum....</div><div class='news' id='new_2'>dolor sit amet...</div></body></html>";
```

Well, if this was on a normal website I could use "getElementsbyClassName" to get all elements with the class I want to select (In my case, "news").
But... If it's like this case, when you have all the html in a variable, how can I get them? Is there a way to get all the divs with class is "news"?

Comment: You could use a virtual dom, then you can use standard DOM functionality https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

Comment: Which environment? Node.js or client-side JS?

Comment: Create element, set innerHTML, element.getElementsByClassName()

Comment: `Well, if this was on a normal website`  I think that explains what we need to know, he want's parsing at the node.js end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) for that:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var myhtml = "<html><body><div class='header'>Welcome</div><div       class='news' id='new_1'>Lorem ipsum....</div><div class='news' id='new_2'>dolor sit amet...</div></body></html>";

var $ = cheerio.load(myhtml);

console.log($('.header').html() );//Welcome
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you so much. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Provided it's client-side JS and jQuery you're talking about (unclear in your tags, mixed env tags):

```
var myhtml= "<html><body><div class='header'>Welcome</div><div class='news' id='new_1'>Lorem ipsum....</div><div class='news' id='new_2'>dolor sit amet...</div></body></html>";
var dom = $.parseHTML(myhtml);
var elem = $(dom).find(".news");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get them the same way it would be on a regular HTML page, the key is to get the elements AFTER they have been created, so your code selecting the class has to come after the code that populates the page. Example:

```
var myhtml= "<html><body><div class='header'>Welcome</div><div     class='news' id='new_1'>Lorem ipsum....</div><div class='news' id='new_2'>dolor sit amet...</div></body></html>";

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("news");

var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
x[i].style.color = "red";
}
```

Comment: This example doesn't work as stated, as there is no statement to apply this HTML to the dom

Answer (score 1):

I have considered a bit different way to solve this problem, first creating a virtual Document then insert that HTML into the virtual Document, then you can find any HTML element using the regular selector, here is the how it goes:

```
let htmlString= "<html><body><div class='header'>Welcome</div><div class='news' id='new_1'>Lorem ipsum....</div><div class='news' id='new_2'>dolor sit amet...</div></body></html>";

let virtualDocument = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("Virtual Document");

virtualDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = htmlString;

selectedEle = virtualDocument.querySelectorAll(".news");

console.log(selectedEle); // Your selected element
```

But take care as using [document.implementation.createHTMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument) and check compatibility table